# Linking kml to Google Maps Javascript API not working

Tags: javascript, xml, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

I'm trying to create a map with pins, it'll end up having hundreds of pins but for now I'm trying with just a few but I can't get it to work. I've tried a lot of different ways of linking it and none of them show.

I think the problem could be the URL I'm using my own server, do I need a diferrent one?

I've tried placing the kml on GitHub and the using that URL, that did not work either.

```js
     var kml_map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_div'), mapOptions); 
  var kml_layer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
          preserveViewport: true,
         url: 'http://zaguan.upc.es/web/movilidad/vitrina/map/etsab.kml'
   }); 
  kml_layer.setMap(kml_map);

    //map.data.loadGeoJson('http://zaguan.upc.es/web/movilidad/vitrina/map/data.json');
    //var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    //url: 'http://zaguan.upc.es/web/movilidad/vitrina/map/etsab.kml'
    //});
    //ctaLayer.setMap(map);

    //google.maps.event.addListener(kmlLayer, "status_changed", function() {
 //  document.getElementById('kmlstatus').innerHTML = "Kml Status:"+kmlLayer.getStatus();
// });
    //var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
        //url: 'http://zaguan.upc.es/web/movilidad/vitrina/map/etsab.kml',
       // map: map
     // });

     //var layer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(kmlPath + '?' + urlSuffix );
    //layer.setMap(map);

        //var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
        //url: 'http://zaguan.upc.es/web/movilidad/vitrina/map/etsab.kml'
        //});
    //ctaLayer.setMap(map);
```

I'm certain the kml works because I can open it on Google Earth and I'll see the pins.

Here's the kml I'm using:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<kml xmlns='http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2'>
    <Document>
        <name>Mobilitat ETSAB</name>
        <description><![CDATA[Programa de mobilitat ETSAB curs 2013/14]]></description>
        <Folder>
            <name>Etsab Mobilitat</name>
            <Placemark>
                <name>EtsaB</name>
                <styleUrl>#icon-123-nodesc</styleUrl>
                <Point>
                    <coordinates>2.1140388999999686,41.38406519999999,0.0</coordinates>
                </Point>
            </Placemark>
            <Placemark>
                <name>Technische Universität Berlin Institut für Architektur</name>
                <styleUrl>#icon-123-nodesc</styleUrl>
                <Point>
                    <coordinates>13.323496299999988,52.51379379999999,0.0</coordinates>
                </Point>
            </Placemark>
            <Placemark>
                <name>Technische Universität Darmstadt Fachbereich Architektur</name>
                <styleUrl>#icon-123-nodesc</styleUrl>
                <Point>
                    <coordinates>8.676702699999964,49.861146500000004,0.0</coordinates>
                </Point>
            </Placemark>
            <Placemark>
                <name>Leibniz Universität Hannover - Fakultät für Architektur und Landschaft</name>
                <styleUrl>#icon-123-nodesc</styleUrl>
                <Point>
                    <coordinates>9.695992,52.393044,0.0</coordinates>
                </Point>
            </Placemark>
        </Folder>

        <Style id='icon-123-nodesc-normal'>
            <IconStyle>
                <scale>1.1</scale>
                <Icon>
                    <href>http://www.gstatic.com/mapspro/images/stock/123-red-dot.png</href>
                </Icon>
                <hotSpot x='16' y='31' xunits='pixels' yunits='insetPixels'>
                </hotSpot>
            </IconStyle>
            <LabelStyle>
                <scale>0.0</scale>
            </LabelStyle>
            <BalloonStyle>
                <text><![CDATA[<h3>$[name]</h3>]]></text>
            </BalloonStyle>
        </Style>

    </Document>

</kml>
```

Comment: The KML as it is works for me, when you are sure that the used URL is correct there is no way to help you when you don't provide the real URL

Comment: the server does not respond

Comment: we changed the URL to the public server. It's this one now: [link] (http://www.etsab.upc.edu/web/movilidad/vitrina/map/etsab.kml)
But it still doen't load the pins
Still trying with 


 ` var kml_map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_div'), mapOptions); 
  var kml_layer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
          preserveViewport: true,
         url: 'http://www.etsab.upc.edu/web/movilidad/vitrina/map/etsab.kml'
   }); `

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was using the wrong server. Thanks Dr.Molle!